# XSLT required for placing the files in target directory

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-2.0, sap-pi

I have a requirement where the source file name is `Rocky_InvoiceNo(uniquevalue)_Timestamp.xml`..

Target system wants the filename to `InvoiceNo(uniquevalue)_Timestamp.xml`.
Can anyone please share the `xslt` code to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

check this code:-

```
        <xsl:variable name="outputpath_1" select="substring-after('Rocky_InvoiceNo(uniquevalue)_Timestamp.xml', '_')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$outputpath_1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The context of your question is not entirely clear.

In general, you can retrieve the filepath of the source XML document using the  `base-uri()` or the `document-uri()` function, e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="source-path" select="base-uri()"/>
```

Then you can remove the `"Rocky_"` part of the filename using:

```
<xsl:variable name="target-path" select="replace($source-path, 'Rocky_', '')"/>
```

and use the resulting path to create a result document using the `xsl:result-document` instruction, e.g.

```
<xsl:result-document href="{$target-path}">
    <!-- your tranformation here -->
</xsl:result-document>
```

However, IMHO it would be much simpler to perform this task by the application that initiates the XSL transformation instead of in the XSLT stylesheet itself.

Comment: Ok ..yes source system is placing a file with filename Rocky_InvoiceNo(uniquevalue)_Timestamp.xml and we need to pick and process to target location by removing the Rocky_ part of the filename and  it should be with InvoiceNo(uniquevalue)_Timestamp.xml.Can you please share the complete xslt code for this.

Comment: No, because I don't know what your XSLT does. I think you have all the parts that are relevant to the problem you have raised. And again, I recommend you do NOT do this in XSLT.